Excel VBA to auto update sort based on calculate column?
I need some help with the sort function VBA macro I have created to track my credits.
So, basically I have 4 columns:



% Used
Credit Limit
Credit Used
Credit Balane




Calculated (C/B)
Manual Update
Manual Update
Calculated (B-C)



Additionally, for "Col_C - Credit_Used" I have added within the macro for adding the decimals.
And, then I call the sort function.
Now, the issue I have is that the sort only works when "Col_C - Credit_Used" is updated and it doesn't sort when "Col_B - Credit_limit" is updated
Macro:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

Dim Rng1 As Range

Set Rng1 = Range("C3:C25")

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng1) Is Nothing Then
If Len(Target) > 2 Then
    Target.Formula = Target.Value / 100
End If

Call SetUsageSort

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub SetUsageSort()

Range("A2:E22").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Credits_24").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Credits_24").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A22"), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Credits_24").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:D22")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Probably using the Worksheet_Calculate event, IIUC.

@BigBen - I am new to excel VBA and the above code is based on my learning. So, any additional inputs is appreciated. thanks

The Worksheet_Change event doesn't fire when formulas recalculate. If you want code to execute in that scenario, you need to use a different event: Worksheet_Calculate.
